# Coding Content Types & Groups in Strapi

Tags: strapi

Is it possible to code the content types and groups in strapi, or does it have to be done via the backend admin gui?

If it is possible, can someone send me a link to the documentation or show how it is done.  I couldn't find anything on this.

Answer (score 1):

Ho! You are right. There is no documentation about creating manually a group.

To create manually a group you will have to create a `./groups` folder in your Strapi project.

Then you will have to create a file for each of your models.

**eg. —** `./groups/openning_hours.json`

This file will have the same structure than a model.

```
{
  "info": {
    "name": "openning_hours",
    "description": ""
  },
  "connection": "default",
  "collectionName": "groups_openning_hours",
  "attributes": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Then if you want to link a Content Type to a group, you will have to update the Content Type model attributes and add a new attribute.

```
"openning_hours": {  <- Will be your attribute name
  "group": "openning_hours", <- Is the group name you created
  "type": "group"
}
```